# bottom 0px attribute modify width unexpectedly in CSS

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a simple chatting web app. This app have 2 separated vertical columns. Left one is for simple message chatting and right one is for uploading various media to sharing with others.

Each column has to place it's own input form at the bottom. Before I set css attribute, the two input form looks like this image

http://postimg.org/image/uo3jkfw5x/

After that, I added this css code {position:fixed; bottom:0px}. So, the input forms go down but some problem happens. The width of input forms becomes not filling the width of each columns.

http://postimg.org/image/hxzb7co7p/

Why this happens? And how do I fix this problem?

I attach my html&css code. I used grid system of twitter bootstrap. Waiting for you help. Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>


    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="../node_modules/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less">
```

```
<style type="text/css">

    html, body, #container { width : 100%; height : 100%;}

    form>div:nth-child(1) { padding-right:0px; }
    form>div:nth-child(2) { padding-left:0px; }

    #talk>form { position:fixed; bottom:0px; }
    #media>form { position:fixed; bottom:0px;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <div id="talk" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <ul id="messages" class="list-unstyled"></ul>
        <form action="" class="row" width="100%">

            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                <input id="m" type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="write message" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Send" >
            </div>

        </form>
    </div>


    <div id="media" class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        <ul class="media-contents" class="list-unstyled"></ul>
        <form action="" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
                <input type="file" class="form-control" accept="image/*"/>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning " value="Upload" >
            </div>
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
</html>
```

Comment: side note: in CSS, `0` has no unit.

Comment: oh, i fix this problem. I changed attribute of form#class from "row" to "row col-sm-6 col-md-6" and the width of form tag work well. I think {position:fixed} attribute in CSS denies some bootstrap grid setting.